# How to organize showing Div and closing

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i working so long on this code and have HTML code and JavaScript.
So this is my HTML code.

```
<div id="showDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > <tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="1" /> 1</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="2" /> 2</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="3" /> 3</td>
</tr></div>
<div id="placeDiv" style="display:none;" class"answer_radio" > <tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="4" /> 4</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="5" /> 5</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="inputC[0]" value="6" /> 6</td>
</tr></div>
<select id="car" value="Show Div" >
<option value="volvo" name="volvo" onclick="showDiv()">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab" name="saab" onclick="placeDiv()">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi" >Audi</option>
```

And JavaScript code:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "block"; 
}
function placeDiv() {
   document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

As you can see if you run that code, it will show drop down list with cars.
If click "volvo",then will display "1,2,3" radio buttons.
If click "saab" ,then will display "4,5,6" radio buttons.
But there is my problem...
If i click first "Volvo" then "Saab" then will show me all 6 radiobuttons.
But i want if i click "Volvo" then "saab" to show only 3 radiobuttons if anyone understand...
I need only "1,2,3" or "4,5,6" radiobuttons to be displayed.
This is not fully completed code,i will do it for other cars...

Comment: Please don't remove the question - the answers mean nothing without the question.

Comment: Thank you after this code i continued by changing,than kyou so much for answer.I changed code a little bit and now working.But after all i used that code before but i forgotten to write some ' :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would help? This isn't a great coding technique though as it's going to lead to a whole lot of code duplication, particularly when you add more cars...

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "block"; 
   document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "none"; 
}
function placeDiv() {
   document.getElementById('placeDiv').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: FINALLY!
Thank you so much!! I used same code that you wrote but i forgot to set some " ' " thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hiding _all_ the previous ones, before showing the relevant may be a better approach, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23131167/216084

Answer (score 1):

Hide all radiobuttons before you make the correct ones visible.

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')).forEach(function (elem, index) {
   elem.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Agree with the concept, though because OP wanted JavaScript solution, therefore was stumped :)